# Asp.net-mvc Identity - Scan Database for broken URLs every two weeks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently developing an app that uses MVC Identity where users can register and whilst doing so they add URLs to the database.

I would like to know the best way to include a script that scans the database and 'flags'/'reports' any broken URLs so they can be manually removed from the database every 2 weeks.

I have found one online in PHP but I would ideally like to do this using C#.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a lot of ways to implement such a code.
all we need to do is to try to download the file , and if its not there( AKA Link broken) it will get exception and return false.

here is an example:

```
public bool checkWebsite(string URL) {
   try {
      WebClient wc = new WebClient();
      string HTMLSource = wc.DownloadString(URL);
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception) {
      return false;
   }
}
```

and usage:

```
//The checkWebsite command will return true:
bool websiteExists = this.checkWebsite("https://www.google.com");
bool websiteExists2 = this.checkWebsite("https://www.beucbeiucbeuiceiuhc.com/nonExist");
```

---

Another **FASTER** way of performing the test is by trying HEAD request instade of GET request. in this way you can improve the speed of the testing.

Here is some example for that method:

```
class MyClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest req = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        return req;
    }
}


public bool checkWebsite(string URL) {
   try {
      MyClient wc = new MyClient();
      string HTMLSource = wc.DownloadString(URL);
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception) {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I set it to run every 2 weeks? Then print a report on the URL's that are broken?

Comment: basicly you need to place this code in a script that will get the urls list from the db , and then process them one by one using the checkWebsite function.   after that you can export the output to file with the current date. and the wrap it all up with scedual task that will run the code every 2 weeks.